# How can I transcribe an audio file stored on the memory on android using the IBM Watson websocket interface?

Tags: android, websocket, ibm-watson, transcription

I went through the tutorial and other questions but found no documentation on how to select a path for a pre-recorded audio file and send it to the service for transcription. I came across this code in the tutorial

`curl -X POST -u <username>:<password>
 --header "Content-Type: audio/flac"
 --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"
 --data-binary @<path>0001.flac
 "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true"`

Can I do something similar on the android sdk which currently implements the websocket interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this [project](https://github.com/mihui/speech-android-sdk) by mihui on Github which has a few slight modifications from the [watson-developer-cloud:master](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-android-sdk). The project by mihui, in addition to the AudioCaptureThread, has a FileCaptureThread which reads bytes from the audio file and writes them to the websocket. This served my purpose of transcribing audio files. Please check this [thread](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/277269/how-do-i-send-an-audio-file-for-transcription-usin/#) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Android-SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk). It's based on the [Java-SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk) but it has functionality specific to Android. You can easily capture audio from the microphone or images from the camera.

Take a look at the examples folder: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk/tree/master/example

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I have been using the android sdk at the above link and that saved me loads of time. However, the repo at https://github.com/mihui/speech-android-sdk also has a FileCapture thread integrated in the project which served my purpose well